# How get access to hidden ItemView in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Hey thanks to stop by !

So there is my issue I got a RecyclerView that can have as much as item i want. And in this when I select on item it grows to show that he is selected. And when I select it I need to unselect my previous selected. But if he is not in view I can't access the view.

I try to put logic to know if it as to be selected or not when he is bind again, but some of the item arn't accessable and don't redraw them self when you swipe so they stay stuck as selected...

Does any one see a workaround?

Thanks for your time, I know there is no code here. But I don't know what I can show you because is more a need of idea then implementing solution.

Comment: You are not supposed to store any data within the views - they are just reflection of your data. There is already a lot of answers with recyclerview selected/checked state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're storing the selected state of items in the RecyclerViewHolders themselves and you shouldn't do that.  The state data that shows up in RecyclerViewHolders should be stored outside of the ViewHolders themselves and passed in as needed during update events.  When you ViewHolders go into and out of view, they will be reset and recreated outside of you control, so a ViewHolder needs to be able to go from it's initial state to a viewable state at any time and you can't rely on the state of a ViewHolder to be maintained.